# Algorithm to calculate nearest location based on longitude & latitude

Tags: c#, linq, google-maps, latitude-longitude

I am currently trying to develop an algorithm to calculate which known locations are closest to current known location.

I have a list of say 100 known locations (meaning I have both long- and latitude). Out of these 100 I pick one location, and after picking that location I want a list to show say the 8 closest known locations to this.

How would a possible solution be to this?

**Edit**

I am not looking for how to calculate distances. I am looking for how to calculate which known locations lies closest to current location.

Example:

Say the list contains 100 locations of movie theaters. I am at theater 5, and I want to find out what other movie theaters in the list lies nearby. Not the distance, but their location.

Comment: By location do you mean lat/lon?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is a [Distance Matrix API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/distancematrix/).  This API allows you to calculate distances between some given positions.

You can do this also by your own with a [`haversine formula`](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)

Comment: Thank you for the links, might become handy later on, but right now I am not looking for how to calculate distances, I am looking for how to find which location are closest to current. Forinstances I am at movie theater 'My theater' and I'm interested in knowing what other theaters lies nearby. Not the distances to them, but their locations.

Comment: But it is still a solution for you ;) You have to get your `My theater` point and all of 100 other locations. Then calculate all 100 distances and pick the smallest one.

To find the nearest point (the smallest distanc) you have to know all of distances.

Comment: At some point you'll have to decide if the _distance_ from current location to x is beyond your threshold...

Comment: Oh, I get it now. My bad. the haversine formula totally did it for me. Thank you for this. Have an upvote

Comment: @hsz, but what if I have a big database and calculating all distances takes much time? Are any optimizations possible?

Comment: I am in the same situation as @levi :(

Answer (score 2):

Try to implement k-d tree algorithm with Nearest neighbor search.

Answer (score 1):

1st idea: If your "100 known locations" remain mostly the same, you could partition the known locations to smaller groups and maintain the structure. Then just play with the closest group.

[More mathematical approaches here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem)

Comment: thanks for suggestion. I will make small groups and use one location per group to calculate initial nearest location.

Answer (score 1):

The below link can be helpful.

http://www.scribd.com/doc/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL