# How to get the nearest X points from point with latitude and longitude?

Tags: asp.net, google-maps, c#-4.0, maps

I have a list of points with latitude and longitude coordinates, from which I want to enter a point say X. I need help coming up with an algorithm to determine the closest 3 list members to that point x.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120872/algorithm-to-calculate-nearest-location-based-on-longitude-latitude

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably have to use the [Haversine Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_circle_distance).  It calculates Great Circle distance between two points on the Earth's surface.  [Here's](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/12types/GreatCircle.java.html) a good article explaining that, and [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/837957/1345119) an answer to a question similar to yours. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

See the method computeDistanceBetween() in the google.maps.geometry.spherical namespace:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical

Then, here's an old V2 demo that uses Array.sort():

http://maps.forum.nu/gm_array_sort.html

You could combine the two, implementing 
computeDistanceBetween() instead of compareDistance() as the sorting function.
Note that this is all done client side.